# Script for Latest Current Firefox Manual Installer

Tags: linux, bash, firefox

well I make the follow Script, to install manual firefox in distros like "Canaima Linux", well I wanna know if posible to get the "Magic Numbers" of "Latest" version in that http folder, to download the latest version, in case exist more files in there.

if possible, how I can make the condition for varible "firefox=firefox-29.0.1.tar.bz2" to get latest number in "firefox=firefox-##.#.#.tar.bz2", this it's possible to make in bash?

```
#!/bin/bash

# Autor : Inukaze (From Venezuela)
# About This Script
# Is a Simple Script to make Manuall Instalation
# Of a Web-Browser called "Firefox"
# For Distros Linux Like : Canaima

firefox=firefox-29.0.1.tar.bz2

rm -rf $HOME/.usuarioenuso
touch $HOME/.usuarioenuso
echo "$USERNAME" >> $HOME/.usuarioenuso
Usuario=$(cat $HOME/.usuarioenuso)
rm -rf $HOME/.usuarioenuso

if [ $(whoami) != root ]; then
    echo
    echo 'Por favor ejecuta este script como root'
    echo 'ó en su defecto usando "sudo" antes del script'
    echo
else

Nucleo=($uname -s)
if  [ "$Nucleo"="Linux" ]; then
        Nucleo="linux"
else
    echo "Este no es un sistema Linux"
    exit 1
fi

# Determinando la arquitectura de la maquina
Arquitectura=$(uname -m)

if              [ "$Arquitectura" = "i386" ]; then
                        Arquitectura="x86"
        elif    [ "$Arquitectura" = "i486" ]; then
                        Arquitectura="x86"
        elif    [ "$Arquitectura" = "i586" ]; then
                        Arquitectura="x86"
        elif    [ "$Arquitectura" = "i686" ]; then
                        Arquitectura="x86"
    elif        [ "$Arquitectura" = "x86_64" ]; then
                        Arquitectura="x86_64"
        else
                echo "Arquitectura -> NO SOPORTADA"
        exit 1
fi 

# Ir al directorio temporal del sistema
sudo mkdir -p /tmp
cd /tmp

# Descargar Firefox segun mi arquitectura


if [ "$Arquitectura" = "x86" ]; then
    echo
    echo "Detectada Arquitectura de 32 Bits"
    echo
    echo "Descargando Firefox de 32 Bits"
    echo


    sudo wget http://mozilla.mirrors.tds.net/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/releases/latest/$Nucleo-i686/es-CL/$firefox

        if [ ! -d /opt ]; then
            sudo mkdir /opt
        fi

    sudo mv firefox-29.0.1.tar.bz2 /opt

    cd /opt
    sudo tar xfvj firefox-29.0.1.tar.bz2
    sudo chmod a+o+x -R firefox

elif [ "$Arquitectura" = "x86_64" ]; then
    echo
    echo "Detectada Arquitectura de 64 Bits"
    echo
    echo "Descargando Firefox de 64 Bits"
    echo

    wget http://mozilla.mirrors.tds.net/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/releases/latest/$Nucleo-x86_64/es-CL/$firefox

        if [ ! -d /opt ]; then
            sudo mkdir /opt
        fi

    sudo mv firefox-29.0.1.tar.bz2 /opt
    cd /opt

    sudo tar xfvj firefox-29.0.1.tar.bz2
    sudo chmod a+o+x -R firefox

else
    echo "Sistema Operativo No Soportado"
fi

cd /opt/firefox
wget http://lh3.ggpht.com/_WlH1qXjuBv8/Sq0yjoub5jI/AAAAAAAADsI/huyfSefOrnY/s512/zoo-red-panda-01.jpg
mv zoo-red-panda-01.jpg icon512x512.jpg
sudo rm -rf /usr/bin/firefox
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/firefox
sudo rm -rf /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo touch /usr/bin/firefox
sudo echo '#!/bin/sh' >> /usr/bin/firefox
sudo echo 'cd /opt/firefox' >> /usr/bin/firefox
sudo echo './firefox "$@" 2>>/dev/null' >> /usr/bin/firefox
sudo echo 'exit' >> /usr/bin/firefox
sudo chmod a+o+x /usr/bin/firefox
sudo touch /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo chmod a+o+x /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo '[Desktop Entry]' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Version=1.0' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Name=Firefox Web Browser' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Name[ar]=متصفح الويب فَيَرفُكْس' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Name[ast]=Restolador web Firefox' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Name[bn]=ফায়ারফক্স ওয়েব ব্রাউজার' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Name[ca]=Navegador web Firefox' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Name[cs]=Firefox Webový prohlížeč' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Name[da]=Firefox - internetbrowser' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Name[el]=Περιηγητής Firefox' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Name[es]=Navegador web Firefox' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Name[et]=Firefoxi veebibrauser' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Name[fa]=مرورگر اینترنتی Firefox' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Name[fi]=Firefox-selain' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Name[fr]=Navigateur Web Firefox' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Name[gl]=Navegador web Firefox' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Name[he]=דפדפן האינטרנט Firefox' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Name[hr]=Firefox web preglednik' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Name[hu]=Firefox webböngésző' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Name[it]=Firefox Browser Web' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Name[ja]=Firefox ウェブ・ブラウザ' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Name[ko]=Firefox 웹 브라우저' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Name[ku]=Geroka torê Firefox' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Name[lt]=Firefox interneto naršyklė' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Name[nb]=Firefox Nettleser' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Name[nl]=Firefox webbrowser' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Name[nn]=Firefox Nettlesar' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Name[no]=Firefox Nettleser' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Name[pl]=Przeglądarka WWW Firefox' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Name[pt]=Firefox Navegador Web' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Name[pt_BR]=Navegador Web Firefox' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Name[ro]=Firefox – Navigator Internet' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Name[ru]=Веб-браузер Firefox' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Name[sk]=Firefox - internetový prehliadač' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Name[sl]=Firefox spletni brskalnik' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Name[sv]=Firefox webbläsare' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Name[tr]=Firefox Web Tarayıcısı' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Name[ug]=Firefox توركۆرگۈ' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Name[uk]=Веб-браузер Firefox' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Name[vi]=Trình duyệt web Firefox' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Name[zh_CN]=Firefox 网络浏览器' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Name[zh_TW]=Firefox 網路瀏覽器' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Comment=Browse the World Wide Web' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Comment[ar]=تصفح الشبكة العنكبوتية العالمية' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Comment[ast]=Restola pela Rede' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Comment[bn]=ইন্টারনেট ব্রাউজ করুন' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Comment[ca]=Navegueu per la web' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Comment[cs]=Prohlížení stránek World Wide Webu' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Comment[da]=Surf på internettet' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Comment[de]=Im Internet surfen' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Comment[el]=Μπορείτε να περιηγηθείτε στο διαδίκτυο (Web)' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Comment[es]=Navegue por la web' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Comment[et]=Lehitse veebi' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Comment[fa]=صفحات شبکه جهانی اینترنت را مرور نمایید' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Comment[fi]=Selaa Internetin WWW-sivuja' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Comment[fr]=Naviguer sur le Web' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Comment[gl]=Navegar pola rede' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Comment[he]=גלישה ברחבי האינטרנט' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Comment[hr]=Pretražite web' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Comment[hu]=A világháló böngészése' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Comment[it]=Esplora il web' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Comment[ja]=ウェブを閲覧します' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Comment[ko]=웹을 돌아 다닙니다' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Comment[ku]=Li torê bigere' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Comment[lt]=Naršykite internete' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Comment[nb]=Surf på nettet' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Comment[nl]=Verken het internet' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Comment[nn]=Surf på nettet' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Comment[no]=Surf på nettet' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Comment[pl]=Przeglądanie stron WWW ' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Comment[pt]=Navegue na Internet' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Comment[pt_BR]=Navegue na Internet' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Comment[ro]=Navigați pe Internet' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Comment[ru]=Доступ в Интернет' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Comment[sk]=Prehliadanie internetu' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Comment[sl]=Brskajte po spletu' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Comment[sv]=Surfa på webben' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Comment[tr]=İnternet te Gezinin' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Comment[ug]=دۇنيادىكى توربەتلەرنى كۆرگىلى بولىدۇ' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Comment[uk]=Перегляд сторінок Інтернету' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Comment[vi]=Để duyệt các trang web' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Comment[zh_CN]=浏览互联网' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Comment[zh_TW]=瀏覽網際網路' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'GenericName=Web Browser' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'GenericName[ar]=متصفح ويب' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'GenericName[ast]=Restolador Web' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'GenericName[bn]=ওয়েব ব্রাউজার' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'GenericName[ca]=Navegador web' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'GenericName[cs]=Webový prohlížeč' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'GenericName[da]=Webbrowser' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'GenericName[el]=Περιηγητής διαδικτύου' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'GenericName[es]=Navegador web' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'GenericName[et]=Veebibrauser' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'GenericName[fa]=مرورگر اینترنتی' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'GenericName[fi]=WWW-selain' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'GenericName[fr]=Navigateur Web' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'GenericName[gl]=Navegador Web' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'GenericName[he]=דפדפן אינטרנט' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'GenericName[hr]=Web preglednik' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'GenericName[hu]=Webböngésző' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'GenericName[it]=Browser web' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'GenericName[ja]=ウェブ・ブラウザ' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'GenericName[ko]=웹 브라우저' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'GenericName[ku]=Geroka torê' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'GenericName[lt]=Interneto naršyklė' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'GenericName[nb]=Nettleser' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'GenericName[nl]=Webbrowser' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'GenericName[nn]=Nettlesar' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'GenericName[no]=Nettleser' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'GenericName[pl]=Przeglądarka WWW' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'GenericName[pt]=Navegador Web' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'GenericName[pt_BR]=Navegador Web' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'GenericName[ro]=Navigator Internet' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'GenericName[ru]=Веб-браузер' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'GenericName[sk]=Internetový prehliadač' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'GenericName[sl]=Spletni brskalnik' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'GenericName[sv]=Webbläsare' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'GenericName[tr]=Web Tarayıcı' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'GenericName[ug]=توركۆرگۈ' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'GenericName[uk]=Веб-браузер' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'GenericName[vi]=Trình duyệt Web' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'GenericName[zh_CN]=网络浏览器' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'GenericName[zh_TW]=網路瀏覽器' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Keywords=Internet;WWW;Browser;Web;Explorer' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Keywords[ar]=انترنت;إنترنت;متصفح;ويب;وب' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Keywords[ast]=Internet;WWW;Restolador;Web;Esplorador' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Keywords[ca]=Internet;WWW;Navegador;Web;Explorador;Explorer' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Keywords[cs]=Internet;WWW;Prohlížeč;Web;Explorer' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Keywords[da]=Internet;Internettet;WWW;Browser;Browse;Web;Surf;Nettet' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Keywords[de]=Internet;WWW;Browser;Web;Explorer;Webseite;Site;surfen;online;browsen' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Keywords[el]=Internet;WWW;Browser;Web;Explorer;Διαδίκτυο;Περιηγητής;Firefox;Φιρεφοχ;Ιντερνετ' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Keywords[es]=Explorador;Internet;WWW' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Keywords[fi]=Internet;WWW;Browser;Web;Explorer;selain;Internet-selain;internetselain;verkkoselain;netti;surffaa' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Keywords[fr]=Internet;WWW;Browser;Web;Explorer;Fureteur;Surfer;Navigateur' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Keywords[he]=דפדפן;אינטרנט;רשת;אתרים;אתר;פיירפוקס;מוזילה;' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Keywords[hr]=Internet;WWW;preglednik;Web' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Keywords[hu]=Internet;WWW;Böngésző;Web;Háló;Net;Explorer' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Keywords[it]=Internet;WWW;Browser;Web;Navigatore' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Keywords[is]=Internet;WWW;Vafri;Vefur;Netvafri;Flakk' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Keywords[ja]=Internet;WWW;Web;インターネット;ブラウザ;ウェブ;エクスプローラ' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Keywords[nb]=Internett;WWW;Nettleser;Explorer;Web;Browser;Nettside' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Keywords[nl]=Internet;WWW;Browser;Web;Explorer;Verkenner;Website;Surfen;Online' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop 
sudo echo 'Keywords[pt]=Internet;WWW;Browser;Web;Explorador;Navegador' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Keywords[pt_BR]=Internet;WWW;Browser;Web;Explorador;Navegador' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Keywords[ru]=Internet;WWW;Browser;Web;Explorer;интернет;браузер;веб;файрфокс;огнелис' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Keywords[sk]=Internet;WWW;Prehliadač;Web;Explorer' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Keywords[sl]=Internet;WWW;Browser;Web;Explorer;Brskalnik;Splet' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Keywords[tr]=İnternet;WWW;Tarayıcı;Web;Gezgin;Web sitesi;Site;sörf;çevrimiçi;tara' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Keywords[uk]=Internet;WWW;Browser;Web;Explorer;Інтернет;мережа;переглядач;оглядач;браузер;веб;файрфокс;вогнелис;перегляд' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Keywords[vi]=Internet;WWW;Browser;Web;Explorer;Trình duyệt;Trang web' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Keywords[zh_CN]=Internet;WWW;Browser;Web;Explorer;网页;浏览;上网;火狐;Firefox;ff;互联网;网站;' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Keywords[zh_TW]=Internet;WWW;Browser;Web;Explorer;網際網路;網路;瀏覽器;上網;網頁;火狐' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Exec=firefox %u' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Terminal=false' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'X-MultipleArgs=false' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Type=Application' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Icon=/opt/firefox/icon512x512.jpg' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Categories=GNOME;GTK;Network;WebBrowser;' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'MimeType=text/html;text/xml;application/xhtml+xml;application/xml;application/rss+xml;application/rdf+xml;image/gif;image/jpeg;image/png;x-scheme-handler/http;x-scheme-handler/https;x-scheme-handler/ftp;x-scheme-handler/chrome;video/webm;application/x-xpinstall;' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'StartupNotify=true' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Actions=NewWindow;NewPrivateWindow;' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo '' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo '[Desktop Action NewWindow]' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Name=Open a New Window' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Name[ar]=افتح نافذة جديدة' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Name[ast]=Abrir una ventana nueva' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Name[bn]=Abrir una ventana nueva' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Name[ca]=Obre una finestra nova' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Name[cs]=Otevřít nové okno' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Name[da]=Åbn et nyt vindue' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Name[de]=Ein neues Fenster öffnen' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Name[el]=Άνοιγμα νέου παραθύρου' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Name[es]=Abrir una ventana nueva' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Name[fi]=Avaa uusi ikkuna' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Name[fr]=Ouvrir une nouvelle fenêtre' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Name[gl]=Abrir unha nova xanela' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Name[he]=פתיחת חלון חדש' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Name[hr]=Otvori novi prozor' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Name[hu]=Új ablak nyitása' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Name[it]=Apri una nuova finestra' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Name[ja]=新しいウィンドウを開く' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Name[ko]=새 창 열기' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Name[ku]=Paceyeke nû veke' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Name[lt]=Atverti naują langą' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Name[nb]=Åpne et nytt vindu' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Name[nl]=Nieuw venster openen' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Name[pt]=Abrir nova janela' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Name[pt_BR]=Abrir nova janela' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Name[ro]=Deschide o fereastră nouă' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Name[ru]=Новое окно' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Name[sk]=Otvoriť nové okno' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Name[sl]=Odpri novo okno' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Name[sv]=Öppna ett nytt fönster' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Name[tr]=Yeni pencere aç' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop 
sudo echo 'Name[ug]=يېڭى كۆزنەك ئېچىش' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Name[uk]=Відкрити нове вікно' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Name[vi]=Mở cửa sổ mới' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Name[zh_CN]=新建窗口' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Name[zh_TW]=開啟新視窗' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Exec=firefox -new-window' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'OnlyShowIn=Unity;' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo '' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo '[Desktop Action NewPrivateWindow]' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Name=Open a New Private Window' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Name[ar]=افتح نافذة جديدة للتصفح الخاص' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Name[ca]=Obre una finestra nova en mode d incògnit' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Name[de]=Ein neues privates Fenster öffnen' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Name[es]=Abrir una ventana privada nueva' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Name[fi]=Avaa uusi yksityinen ikkuna' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Name[fr]=Ouvrir une nouvelle fenêtre de navigation privée' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Name[he]=פתיחת חלון גלישה פרטית חדש' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Name[hu]=Új privát ablak nyitása' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Name[it]=Apri una nuova finestra anonima' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Name[nb]=Åpne et nytt privat vindu' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Name[ru]=Новое приватное окно' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Name[sl]=Odpri novo okno zasebnega brskanja' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Name[tr]=Yeni bir pencere aç' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Name[uk]=Відкрити нове вікно у потайливому режимі' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Name[zh_TW]=開啟新隱私瀏覽視窗' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'Exec=firefox -private-window' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
sudo echo 'OnlyShowIn=Unity;' >> /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

You could wget the directory and then grep/sed out the url (or xpath if it's available).